How can I enqueue styles if a class exists in body in Wordpress page
I am trying to load some stylesheets only on certain "pages" that contain a specific class on a Wordpress website.
I want to load stylesheets
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
  wp_dequeue_style('my-child');
  wp_enqueue_style('style1_css', '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/assets/style1.css' , 'all' );
  wp_enqueue_style('style2_css', '/wp-content/plugins/myplugin/assets/style1.css' , 'all' );
}, 1 );

I have tried all sorts of suggestions like the following that is not working.
function check_class_in_content($class) {
    if (is_singular()) {
        global $post;
        if (strpos($post->post_content, $class) !== false) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

if (check_class_in_content('page-id-2022')) {
    echo 'Class exists in the content of this page.';
} else {
    echo 'Class does not exist in the content of this page.';
}

Keeps saying class does not exist, but in my body tag I do have the class page-id-2022.
What am I doing wrong and how can I get it to work?
Thanks

Themes usually add classes to the body through a function called body_class(). https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/

To see which classes are added you can use the filter hook body_class. If you use this hook with a high priority, you will get all the classes that will get added to the body.

If your target class is in there you can  then add your piece of code. But note that any output will get printed in the body tag. Which is not what you will want to do. Instead of echo’ing something is would be better to add a new filter/action. add_action('wp_footer', 'method') and in your function method you can do your stuff.

But instead of all this: in your example you are looking for page-id-2022 which is a single post id.

Here are several ways to check the current ID on frontend pages: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/161711/how-to-get-current-page-id-outside-the-loop

First, you can use the get_body_class() function, which returns the classes array of the page body. Check if the given class exists in the array. And enqueue the CSS only if the class exists in the body of the page.
Try the following code:
function singular_css( $class, $csshandle ){
    if( ! is_singular() ) return;
    if (in_array($class, get_body_class())) {
        wp_enqueue_style($csshandle);
    }
}
function custom_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_register_style('style1_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/style1_css.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    wp_register_style('style2_css', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'css/style2_css.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all');
    
    singular_css('page-id-466', 'style1_css');
    singular_css('page-id-155', 'style2_css');

}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'custom_enqueue_styles');

Code tested and works.

Yes that worked, very much appreciated :)

Done, sorry I forgot to do that :)
